# delete rows with 2 columns containing specific data

Tags: excel, vba, macros

I have an excel file containing one sheet which this data:

```
      A    |     B      |     C    |       D
________________________________________________
    321        2016/12/01    0           0
    123        2016/12/03    23          0
    1321       2016/12/05    12          1
    2315       2015/12/03    0           0
    23154      2015/12/03    0           0
```

I do want to delete all rows if the value from C `AND` D is 0. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete row based on cell value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613609/how-to-delete-row-based-on-cell-value)

Comment: Yep, it is possible to be a duplicate. But in my case there are 2 columns which can be in the condition of delete the row

Comment: In your case, it should be a matter of just adding to the code to take into consideration both column C and D, instead of just one column (is that what you are saying in your comment?)

Comment: A quick example for me then? for let say 4 columns in the condition?

Comment: If I had to guess (I don't know VBA), you would add to the `Do While` in the answer to include both of your columns.  Perhaps something like: `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count && ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count`

Comment: So, you don't know VBA

Comment: No, not really. I've worked with it once using ASP.NET, but that's not the point.  The point is, the _possible_ duplicate may be able to help you.  If it doesn't, then fine, if it does, then this question is essentially a duplicate of that question.  That's why its a _possible_ duplicate.

Comment: Is it just me or is there an elephant in the room singing "I want someone to do my code for me"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure you have first row as header one and then use this:

```
Sub Main()
    With Worksheets("mySheetName")
        With .Range("D1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=0
            .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=0
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: With - not allowed outside as a procedure.

Comment: you have to wrap that code in a `Sub WhateverName()` `End Sub` block! See edited code

Comment: @FlorinM., did you get through it?

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Sub RowKiller213()
    Dim i As Long, N As Long

    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "C").Value = 0 And Cells(i, "D").Value = 0 Then
            Cells(i, "C").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

***Note:***

- the loop runs bottom-up

Comment: Thanks for your response. "Object reference not found"

Answer (score 0):

Short Googling gave me multiple approaches:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/815-excel-remove-rows-based-on-cell-value.html

Comment: In your link, it doesn't give an example for considering 2 or 3 or 10 columns having their values to be compared to 0

Answer (score 0):

Apply filter to cols C and D where value is 0, and delete the displayed rows.