# Deleting rows based on a range of data

Tags: excel, vba, range, rows

I'd like to delete entire rows in the first sheet if cells in column E contains the same name that is found in range `B1:B30` in worksheet `Ark3`. I attempted using below code, but it returns

> Run-time error '13', Type mismatch.

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Contains_String_Text_Value()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 500
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Ark3").Range("B1:B30") Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You are comparing a single value against an array of values. You also checking 500 values one-by-one against a static range of 30 values. Can you explain: Does the value from your current cell must be in the **same** row to be deleted *or* only when the value **occurs** in the `Range` of `B1:B30`?

Comment: read this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613609/how-to-delete-row-based-on-cell-value

Comment: @JvdV If a value in any cell in the row of the active sheet `(Ark1)` occurs in the of `B1:B30`  `Worksheet(Ark3)` I would like that entire row to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient way of comparing one value with many others is to use a [dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object) as a lookup table. Note : In the example below I have commented out the delete statement for you to confirm correct operation.

```
 Option Explicit

 Sub sbDelete_Rows_Matching()

   Dim wsFirst, wsArk3 As Worksheet
   With ThisWorkbook
     Set wsFirst = .Sheets(1)
     Set wsArk3 = .Sheets("Ark3")
   End With

   ' create lookup table
   Dim lookup
   Set lookup = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
   Dim cell As Range, key As String
   For Each cell In wsArk3.Range("B1:B30").Cells
     key = cell.Value
     If Len(key) > 0 Then
       If lookup.exists(key) Then
         MsgBox "Ark3 has duplicate value" & vbCr & key, vbCritical, "Warning"
       Else
         lookup.Add key, cell.row
       End If
     End If
   Next cell

   ' process sheet 1
   Dim r, count, lastRow As Long
   count = 0
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   With wsFirst
     lastRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
     For r = lastRow To 1 Step -1
       If lookup.exists(.Cells(r, 5).Value) Then
         .Cells(r, 5).Interior.Color = vbYellow
         ' .Rows(r).Delete
         count = count + 1
       End If
     Next r
     .Range("A1").Select
   End With
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   MsgBox count & " rows deleted"

 End Sub
```