# VBA Macro for deleting repeated headers/meta data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook that includes duplicated headers and a page number that I want to remove via vba macro.

The below screenshot repeats itself throughout my workbook, I have tried to write a macro that finds the specific text and delete but causes the data to shift incorrectly and is wildly inefficient. The rows in between the headers are not always 3 so I can't have a macro that blindly deletes 5 rows every x rows. For clarity, I am trying to delete the bolded text while not losing the integrity of the unbolded data.

[image]

Is it possible to have a macro that goes over a specific range to delete the repeated headers and metadata depicted above?

Macro attempted to use from [How to delete row based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613609/how-to-delete-row-based-on-cell-value). Understandably changing the text for each header / metadata is not a reasonable solution and causes the data shift.

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithHyphen()

    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("A2:A20") 'Range of values to loop through

        If InStr(1, rng.Value, "Page 1 of 10") > 0 Then 'InStr returns an integer of the position, if above 0 - It contains the string
            rng.Delete
        End If

    Next rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include the code you are working on to do this in your question if you need help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can delete all rows that are not number in column. If so then try ..

```
Sub DeleteNonNumberRows()
Dim rng As Range, Cl As Range, DelRng As Range
LRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Range("A1", "A" & LRow)

For Each Cl In rng
    If IsNumeric(Cl) = False Or Cl = "" Then
        If DelRng Is Nothing Then
        Set DelRng = Cl
        Else
        Set DelRng = Union(DelRng, Cl)
        End If
    End If
Next

DelRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Note that rng is starting from A1. Change it as suitable.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you for your response!